# Redux Framework - multi select with commas

Tags: jquery, wordpress, redux-framework

I created a slider in wordpress and for ther transition effects I have used the select field of the redux framework.

[image]

I checked the article [here](https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/select/)

but Im not sure why is not working.
below is the field that I have created in redux config

```
             array(
                 'id' => 'slide-transition',
                 'type' => 'select',
                'multi' => true,
                 'title' => __('Slide Transition Effects', 'gazi'),
                 'subtitle' => __('Choose the transition effects for the slides, you can also use all effects together.', 'gazi'),
                 'options' => array('slide' => __('Slide','gazi'), 'elastic' => __('Elastic','gazi'), 'fade' => __('Fade','gazi'), 'blocks' => __('Blocks','gazi')), //Must provide key => value pairs for select options
                 'default'  => array('slide','elastic','fade','blocks')
             ),
```

output:

```
   global $gazment;
            $slide_transition = isset( $gazment['slide-transition'] ) ? $gazment['slide-transition'] : null;
            if( !is_array( $slide_transition ) ){
                $slide_transition = (array)$slide_transition;
            }
```

and the out put in javascriptis:

```
},
transition:"<?php echo $slide_transition; ?>",
scalemode:"fill",
isfullscreen:false,
textformat: {
}
```

but it doesnt work because when i see the page source its something like this  `transition:"Array",` I dont know what Im doing wrong, I need to get the selected elements with commas like:`transition:"slide,elastic,fade,blocks",` how can I fix this?

any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved using in array like the code below

```
transition:"<?php if (in_array('slide', $slide_transition)) { echo 'slide,'; } if (in_array('elastic', $slide_transition)) { echo 'elastic,'; } if (in_array('fade', $slide_transition)) { echo 'fade,'; } if (in_array('blocks', $slide_transition)) { echo 'blocks,'; } ?>", scalemode:"fill",isfullscreen:false, textformat: {}
```

thanks to php.net :)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php